# Crystal 2011 - Changed DB Name now report won't run

Tags: crystal-reports

We have a crystal report (2011) that was running fine until we changed our DB name.  We knew it would break it, but how can I change the DB name in the report so it points to the new DB?  I've changed it in the DB Expert and it shows that it's pointing to the new location, but everytime I try to run it, it errors out saying it can't find the old dabatbase name.

Any ideas?

Comment: After a little more digging and help from a coworker, I found out how.  I figured I'd post it to help anyone else out.

Open the report in Crystal and choose Database, Set Location from the menu.  Under Current Data Source, expand any SP you might have and click Properties.  Check the Catalog in there, if it's not set correctly, then you'll need to change the settings in the Database Expert.  But for others, go to the Replace With section and expand the node until you find the SP you want to use (it will be the same name but have the new DB information stored in it) and click Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need, under the Database menu, do a Set Location and UPDATE your data sources.